# MSSQL Pivot for multiple column

Tags: sql-server

I had a multiple column table. The information are vertical inserted.

I used pivot to reorganise it but wasn't sure how to loop through all the column.

Anyone had experience in this?

[image]

I broke into 5 view for each GI_Col_1 and combine into 1 view. Can i write it in a single query?

[image]

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Yes, I had. And you? :) What have you tried to do?

Comment: Im sorry. i try to convert into " Supplier_Size, UPC, HTS 1, HTS 2'........

Comment: SELECT        *
FROM   (SELECT    
    [batchid], [GI_TITLE], [GI_Col_1]
  FROM        
 [HKSA].[dbo].[NSPODetails]) AS s PIVOT (MIN([GI_Col_1]) FOR [GI_TITLE] IN 
 ([VPN], [StyleDescription], [SupplierColor], [Class], [SUPPLIER SIZE], [UPC], [HTS 1], [HTS 2], [HTS 3], [HTS 4], 
  [1ST COST USD], [1ST COST FRGN], [TOTAL UNITS], [TOTAL COST USD], [TOTAL COST FRGN], [REGULAR PRICE],
   [PROMO PRICE], [MUP REGULAR], [MUP PROMO])) AS pvt

Comment: Add Sample data with expected output not screen shots